# Move Git Repo to submodule of itself

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have cloned a (gui) library repo into a local repo and now find I think a better structure would be to have that as a sub module, where my main code lives in the parent directory/repo.

What is the best way to move the files that currently live in the repo to be moved to a sub-module repo? Or maybe the I should be adding a repo as a parent? (Preserving the existing name and submodule with a new name).

now:

- library Repo (Repo1)

after:

- My Code in (Repo1)

  - Library Repo in (Repo1-Submodule1)

This is the simple case where I currently have not custom code in the repo. So everything that currently lives in it needs to move (or become a child of parent repo).

Comment: Until you know what you are doing, I would recommend staying away from submodules.  Instead use the packaging system normally used with the language you are working in, to create a module of the library that your code can use.  For Java that would be Maven.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen this is probably good advice..(after googling around a bit more).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right setup would be:

```
My Code in (Repo2)
    Library Repo in (Repo1-Submodule1)
```

Meaning:

- you keep Library Repo in `Repo1` unchanged, where it it.
- you create a *second* repo for your code.
- you add `Repo1` as a submodule in `Repo2`.

That is:

```
cd Repo2
git submodule add -- /url/to/Repo1
```

(Here you would use the url of Repo1, not its local path as initially cloned)